# How do I use a modified keyboard layout in xubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xubuntu, xfce, xkb

I have created a modified xkb symbols keymap that I want to use in my xubuntu installation but I can't see it in the list of layouts in the settings dialog.

I put

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "psvorak" {
name[Group1]="Sweden - PSvorak";
include "keypad(comma)"
include "level3(ralt_switch)"

key <AD01>  { [odiaeresis, Odiaeresis, dollar, none ]   };
<etc>
};
```

at the end of /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se but no dice.

I also tried to regenerate symbols.dir according to http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/problem-creating-custom-xkb-layout-605568/ and while xkbcomp says there are no faults in my file, nothing else changes. It isn't available in the gui and setxkbmap (with its very confusing syntax) only responds with 'couldnt find file' or 'error loading new keyboard description'.

Also; I dont have a /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

Where am I supposed to place a keymap so that xfce can find and use it?

---

*Edit:*

I did manage to create a console key map and load it using loadkeys...

```
charset "iso-8859-1"
keymaps 0-2,4-6,8,12
alt_is_meta
strings as usual
keycode   1 = Escape
    alt     keycode   1 = Meta_Escape
keycode   2 = one              exclam
    alt     keycode   2 = Meta_one
keycode   3 = two              quotedbl         at
    control keycode   3 = nul
    alt     keycode   3 = Meta_two
<etc>
```

... but it only seems to work in the Ctrl-Alt-F1 console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the xkb layout to show up in the gui where keyboard layouts are selected, a corresponding `<variant>` node has to be added to the proper `<layout>` section of the /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml file